# How to wrap a string after EVERY div tag with beautifulSoup?

Tags: beautifulsoup

How can I get this wrap:

```js
soup.div.string.wrap(soup.new_tag('head'))`
```

not just in the first div, but in all divs?

This did not work either:

```js
for tag in soup.find_all('div'):
soup.div.string.wrap(soup.new_tag('head'))
```